# AD user disabled date is in extensionAttribute, need to delete users based on that

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We have a third party LDAP system managing people. AD users that represent actual employees are created and maintained by a feed from this LDAP system. We would like the date that a user is disabled in the LDAP system to be sent to a particular AD user attribute, for example extentionAttribute9.

From there I would try get-aduser to search extentionAttribute9 for ones with a date older than 90 days. The problem of course is that this extended attribute would contain a string value and I can't seem to get that read as a date.

I can do this to get users created more than 90 days ago and I wish I could do the same for the extension attribute populated with the date:

```
$Date = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-90)

get-aduser -filter {created -lt $Date} -SearchBase "OU=User_Test,DC=foo,DC=com"
```

I've tried a few things, including with outside help, but probably nothing worth posting here as nothing has really come close.

If I can't get this to work, I'll search for users who are disabled and haven't logged in for more than 90 days, but doing it based on a disabled date would be more definitive.

Comment: What date format is used to set a date in this extensionattribute? Once you have decided on that, it should be easy enough to convert that back to a real datetime object so you can compare against your reference date.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing the format.

Since that format won't work with just a simple cast to datetime. We need to parse it as is and convert it to datetime. From there cast it to string with 'yyyy-MM-dd' as the format.

*EDIT:*
The error code in the comment is due to ':' in .Trim. As the variable being trimmed does not contain ':' it is throwing the error.

Changed from using '.Trim()' (this would only remove white space) to '-replace '\W' '. Doing this allows us to more easily remove non-alphanumeric characters from the variable.

Let me know if this works for you.

```
$Date = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-90)
$Pattern = '[^a-zA-Z]'
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=User_Test,DC=foo,DC=com" | 
   Where {([datetime]::ParseExact($($_.extensionAttribute9 -replace '\W'), 'yyyyMMdd', $null).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')) -lt $Date}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The date format used is like this, for example: 20220105

Comment: I think there are a couple of problems. Using [DateTime], there doesn't seem to be a way to change the date format, such as you can do using get-date. But I think the bigger obstacle is with commands that expect a date to be passed from extensionattribute9, which is passing a string value.

Comment: Try the updated answer. By using parseexact we should solve the problem. Alternatively, you can use Search-ADAccount to find inactive accounts greater than xx days.

Comment: It seems that it's still having a hard time recognizing the string as a date:     Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:96
+ ... u" | Where {([datetime]::ParseExact($_.extensionAttribute9, 'yyyyMMdd ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

Comment: As for searching for inactive accounts, I need to limit it to user accounts that are disabled and inactive.

My fallback would be to use the commands below, but I think taking the actual date that a user is disabled is a better option, which is why I would like to at least try, though it's proving tough.

$Date = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-90)

get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=UserAccts,DC=foo,DC=com" -Properties LastLogonDate | Where-Object Enabled -eq $False | Where-Object LastLogonDate -lt $Date

Comment: Updated the answer. Added '.Trim()' to the first one to clear any blank spaces. If that doesn't work. Try one of the other solutions targeting the lastlogondate attribute.

Comment: I should have been more clear. I actually already have a script to get all disabled users who have not logged on for 90 days or more. FYI: LastLogonDate is just a friendly version of LastLogonTimeStamp, which is replicated amongst all DCs. Checking an account that I know hasn't logged on in a couple of weeks against all DCs, it matches on each one, where LastLogon is different on each.

Comment: Below is part of the error I currently get on the attempt to get the date from extensionAttribute9. (Limited on characters so can't post the whole error.) If I pipe extensionAttribute9 to FL, it looks like eg: extensionAttribute9 : 20220105     
"You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:122
+ ... [datetime]::ParseExact($(($_.extensionAttribute9).Trim(' : ')), 'yyyy ...
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull"

Comment: Changed the code to use -replace '\W' instead of .Trim(). This should remove any non-alphanumeric characters from the string.